# I have uploaded csv files due to big size on server, I want to know if it's possible to read csv and convert in json.... in api side not client side

Tags: papaparse

I have uploaded csv files due to big size on server,
I want to know if it's possible to read csv and convert in json in api side not client side

```
  const csvFilePath = require('../../../public/uploads/abc.csv');
     Papa.parse(csvFilePath, {
         header: true,
         download: true,
         skipEmptyLines: true,
         step: function (row) {
             console.log("Row:", row.data);
         },
         complete: function (results) {
             console.log("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
             console.log(results);
         }
     });
```

but unexpected.. result

[Response.... getting...something...csv string but missing something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M7XQ.png)

Comment: Could you maybe share your result and a sample from the CSV file? Parsing this on the backend should be definitely possible.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NDAs6ncsasWnGoKlm_FHxXYUuXRtRJnq/view?usp=sharing